# Treeview tmp.plugin is not a function

Tags: jquery, treeview

I am trying to use jquery treeview for multiple selection for my product but when my code come to **jstree** the code gives me this error  'tmp.plugin is not a function'

```
 $('#TreeViewPopup').click(function (f) {
        $('#TreeViewModal').modal('toggle');
        $('#tree').jstree({
            plugins: ['sort', 'types', 'checkbox'],
            'core': {
                'data': {
                    "url": function () {
                        return '@Url.Content("~/TechnicalService/Technical/FullTreeView")' + '?ProductID=' + $("#SelectProductID").val();
                    }, "dataType": "json",
                }
            }
        });
```

I havent solved my this error yet. if you have any idea help me pls.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I got  this error ;   'tmp.plugin is not a function'